# how can I get the WPF DataGrid's Row CheckBox's Checked Event in code behind

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I am having following WPf DataGrid

```
<UserControl x:Class="abc.WPFApp.UCGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WPFtoolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:abc.WPFApp">

    <UserControl.Resources>
<!--Restrict editing based on IsVariable-->
        <Style x:Key="CheckBoxCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsVariable}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
        <WPFtoolkit:DataGrid x:Name="UCdataGridView" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                                     CellStyle="{StaticResource defaultCellStyle}"
                                                     RowStyle="{StaticResource defaultRowStyle}"
                                                     ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource defaultDataGridColumnHeader}"
                                                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                                     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                                                     RowBackground="White" 
                                                     AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue"
                                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Extended" RowHeaderWidth="20"
                                     CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
                                     CanUserResizeColumns="True" AllowDrop="True" KeyUp="UCGridKeyUp" >
            <WPFtoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>


<WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="dgChkRepeatingData" Binding="{Binding Path=MasterDataFlag}" MaxWidth="135" MinWidth="80"
                                     Header="Repeating data" Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="{Binding (IsVariable)}" 
                                     EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}"
                                      >
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="100" Header="Max Element" x:Name="dgChkMaxElement"
                                                   Binding="{Binding Path=MaxElement}" MinWidth="70" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}">
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn MaxWidth="100" Header="In For Loop" x:Name="dgChkInForLoop"
                                                   Binding="{Binding Path=InForLoop}" MinWidth="70" Visibility="Collapsed" 
                                    EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource CheckBoxCellStyle}">
                </WPFtoolkit:DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

                <WPFtoolkit:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="dgXPath" Binding="{Binding Path=XPath}" Header="XPath" Width="500"
                                               Visibility="Collapsed" IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsVariable}"
                                               EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource TextBoxCellStyle}"/>
</WPFtoolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        </WPFtoolkit:DataGrid>
```

Now how can i get the checked event of various columns in code behind file.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle **SourceUpdated** event of the binding on DataGridCheckBoxColumn. To get this event you need to also set

```
NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true
```

on that binding